# how to change titles in ggplot for series of plots?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I created a function that splits a dataframe by group variable 'gear' and makes plots for each new df. How do I change the title for each plot then?

```
    rank20 <- function(df){
      sdf <- df
      clusterName <- paste0("cluster",sdf$gear)
      splitData <- split(sdf,clusterName)
      plot <- lapply(splitData, function (x) {ggplot(x, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()+
          labs(x="mpg", y="cyl",
               title="This Needs To Be Changed") + 
          theme_minimal()})
      do.call(grid.arrange,plot)
    }
    rank20(mtcars)
```

I want the following titles: gear3, gear4, etc. (corresponding to their gear value)
[image]

UPD: both results are right if using mtcars. But in my real case, I transform my initial df. So, I should have put my question in the different way. I need to take the titles from splitData df name itself rather than from the column.

Comment: Not tested, but have you tried the `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` argument to `mapply()`?

Comment: Hey @Yulia Kentieva, would be great to reproduce this function with a public dataset like `data(mtcars)` or `data(diamonds)`, also would be great to see your expected output.

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez thank you! I changed it to mtcars. I hope it's better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier with `lapply` to use the indexes as the input. Provides more flexibility if you need to link the list to another element eg the name of the list:

```
rank20 <- function(df, col="gear"){
  sdf <- df
  clusterName <- paste0("cluster", sdf[[col]])
  splitData <- split(sdf, clusterName)
  # do the apply across the splitData indexes instead and pull out cluster
  # name from the column
  plot <- lapply(seq_along(splitData), function(i) {
    X <- splitData[[i]]
    i_title <- paste0(col, X[[col]][1])
    ## to use clusterName instead eg cluster3 instead of gear3:
    #i_title <- paste0(col, names(splitData)[i])
    ggplot(X, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
      geom_point() +
      labs(x="mpg", y="cyl", title=i_title) + 
      theme_minimal()
  })
  do.call(grid.arrange,plot)
}
rank20(mtcars)
```

As you say you wanted the name to be `gear2`, `gear3` I've gone with this but hashed out the alternative `i_title` that uses the `clusterName` value instead.

In the input of the function you can change the `col` value to switch to a different column so `gear` isn't hard-coded

Comment: thank you, it works for mtcars. But I change the initial dataframe. I should have put my question in a different way. I need to take the titles from splitData df name itself rather than from the column. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep, that's in the answer. See the hashed out line `#i_title <- paste0(col, names(splitData)[i])` for that option :)

Comment: oh I didn't see that. Thank you! it works!

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a slightly different approach (yet also using the loop over indices as suggested in [user Jonny Phelps answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65582937/7941188)). I am creating a list of plots and then using patchwork::wrap_plots for plotting. I find it smoother.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

len_ind <- length(unique(mtcars$cyl))

ls_plot <-
  mtcars %>%
  split(., .$cyl) %>%
  map2(1:len_ind, ., function(x, y) {
    ggplot(y, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "mpg", y = "cyl", 
           title = names(.)[x]
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  })

wrap_plots(ls_plot) + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Just noticed this was the wrong column - using cyl instead of gear. Oops. It was kind of fun to wrap this into a function:

```r
plot_col <- function(x, col, plotx, ploty){
len_ind <- length(unique(mtcars[[col]]))
x_name <- deparse(substitute(plotx))
y_name <- deparse(substitute(ploty))

ls_plot <-
  mtcars %>%
  split(., .[[col]]) %>%
  map2(1:len_ind, ., function(x, y) {
    ggplot(y, aes({{plotx}}, {{ploty}})) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = x_name, y = y_name,
           title = names(.)[x]
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  })

wrap_plots(ls_plot) + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
}

plot_col(mtcars, "gear", mpg, cyl)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it works for mtcars. But I change the initial dataframe. I should have put my question in a different way. I need to take the titles from splitData df name itself rather than from the column. Is that possible?

Comment: @YuliaKentieva not quite sure what you mean. In the example of mtcars, what name would you want to appear in the title then ?